# Tensorflow: Too many values to unpack error when loading data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am learning machine learning and I am trying to do image classification. I am at the point to define my train and test data from the directory, but I am getting an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REjfS.png):

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pathlib

data_dir = "C:/Users/efsol/OneDrive/Classification"
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')))
print(image_count)
data_dir.is_dir()

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(data_dir)

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` generates [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) and not of the form (train_images, train_labels) hence the `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` to fix this:

```
# Train split
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  )

# Validation/test split
val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  )

# This will print all the classes
class_names = train_ds.class_names
print(class_names)

# you can use tf.keras.layers.Rescaling to Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
normalization_layer = layers.Rescaling(1./255)
normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))
first_image = image_batch[0]
print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image))
```

please refer to this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) for complete code